# multiple segments with variable heights CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
+---------------------------+
+ row 1: fixed height 40px  +
+---------------------------+
+ row 2: fixed height 40px  +
+---------------------------+
+                           +
+ row 3: variable height    +
+ display all user content  +
+                           +
+---------------------------+
+                           +
+ row 4: variable height,   +
+ whatever space is left.   +
+ Table scroll              +
+                           +
+---------------------------+
+ row 5: fixed height 40px  +
+---------------------------+
```

Can someone help me with the CSS for this?  The 2 rows of variable heights is throwing me off.  Also, as I understand it, with a table scroll, I need to tell it the height needed.  But, if this is calculated depending on row 3, how do I do this?  I've been playing with something like this (row is bootstrap grid):

CSS:

```
div.row1, div.row2, div.row5 {
    height: 40px;
}
div.row3 {
    /* No styling so the height can grow as needed */
}
div.row4, div.table-scroll {
    /* How do I set the height here? */
    overflow:auto;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row row1">
    some content here
</div>
<div class="row row2">
    some content here
</div>
<div class="row row3">
    <div ng-repeat="blah"> Hello </div>
</div>
<div class="row row4">
    <div class="table-scroll">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="blah">
                <td>text</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row row5">
    :w
</div>
```

The sum of row1-height, row2-height, row3-height, row4-height, row5-height should be 100%

Comment: the sum of the various heights should be equal to... what?

Comment: Updated.  The sum of the heights for row1, row2, row3, row4, row5 should be 100%

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible as of today: 
[Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space#)

You would have to use javascript to calc the side see the first answer in the link.

If you don't mind setting the size then here is a fiddle for a somewhat fixed height: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poi33/aoy0rg55/)

I set the widths to:

```
#rowlarge {
    height: 70%;
}
#rowsmall {
    height: 30%;
}
```

Comment: Please post a comment before downvoting